# Messages in $.ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a `ajax` function in my view file looks like this:

```
...
<div id="success" class="hidden">
  <?php echo TbHtml::alert(TbHtml::ALERT_COLOR_SUCCESS, 'Maraqlar qeydə alındı.'); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div id="error1" class="hidden">
  <?php echo TbHtml::alert(TbHtml::ALERT_COLOR_ERROR, 'Yalnışlıq baş verdi. Əməliyyatı icra etmək üçün ən azı bir maraq dairəsi seçilməlidir.'); ?>
</div>
<input type="button" id="checkbox" value="checkbox" class="btn btn-success" />

...
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url : '<?=Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/ideyalar/maraglaridaxilet',
      cache: false,
      data: 'i='+$i+'&idm='+$idm+'&ids='+$ids,
  //    beforeSend:function(data){
  //        location.reload();
  //    },
      complete:function(data){
          $("#error1").addClass("hidden");
          location.reload(); // where I must put this line ?
          $("#success").removeClass("hidden");
      },
      error:function(data){
          $("#error").removeClass("hidden");
      }
  });
}
...
```

There is no problem everything working correctly. But I want to do this:
if everything OK, first page must reload, and then `$("#success").removeClass("hidden");`.

P.S: when I remove comment from `location.reload();` firstly it shows success message box, and then reload. But I want to do this *other way round*.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using ajax, then y u need to reload page??

Comment: yes I need. Because it prevents some conflicts in my **db**.

Comment: After you reloaded the page, how do you expect the previous AJAX call to still control it? It's done, executed, nothing else to do. That's another logic issue for you to get sorted out.

Comment: I know guy. and I know the how this function works. because I wrote this function. So, how to reload ?
P.S: there is no any logic issue. You can be sure  :)

Comment: No, there's no logic issue at all. See this... You want to finish an AJAX call, reload the page (new context, new state, etc) and _magically_ make that previous call interact with the new page's DOM. AJAX calls are meant to be asynchronous, and one of the biggest advantages is that you don't need a full page refresh. If you want a synchronous call, don't use AJAX.

Comment: okay I understand. and in this point I don't need refresh the page ?

Comment: If all you need is to manipulate some elements, like you're doing already in the success callback, then no. Like I said before, if for some reason you still need to refresh the page, then you need to look for a different solution. Or you don't really need the refresh, or you can't use AJAX.

Comment: the main problem this: 

I have 30 checkboxes and 7 radio buttons in my page. User can select some of these checkboxes and a radio. After this if user selected some of them and then click the button (which has a `id="checkbox"`) it must be inserts the selected values to **db**. There is no problem, everything work correctly ! 

But if I don't reload the page, checkboxes and radios aren't resets their *selected* **values**. In this point user can click the button second time. Of course AJAX function works and again inserts the same values in **db**. For the user there are no any problem.

Comment: But the several same records in **db table** maybe *creates* the problems for me (*in the future...*). 

Thus, I want to reload the page, to prevent the problems for the future. 

P.S: If bad, sorry for my English. :)

Comment: So you should do a regular submit just like any form, and stop using AJAX.